# Relay contact side protection

Tags: relay, safety, emc

Do we need any protection on the contact side of the relay (Ex: form C 240V 3A) if the contact side is not powered by the circuit.

if we have to protect, then how(Please provide an example).

Also, do we need to have any EMC/EMI protection such as saftey Cap, MOV, or etc?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr9mO2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I've never added any, but I've only switched an amp or so.  Here are 8 5A relays controlled by a Mega2560 driving indivdual transistors to energergize the relays.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukRtgLK_b5c  And the same kind or relays with TPIC6C595 shift register to energize the relays, controlled by an Uno https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSuCrGYORwc

Comment: That's what I thought too. This board is meant for industrial applications, so I would like to make sure. Because I see some circuit has a Saftey capacitor to earth ground.

Comment: Because this is a general purpose module, I'd say no. The user may need to add a snubber or freewheeling diode to protect the contacts depending on the load.

You could add some kind of RC snubber if your not sensitive to cost, since that will work with DC and AC